# Connect Visual Studio with MySQL database using Server Explorer

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I would like to connect the Visual Studio (2015) Server Explorer with a MySQL-DB. Having installed the latest *MySQL for Visual Studio* and *Connector/NET*, I still get the following error:

[image]

When I connect a C#-application in Visual Studio to a MySQL-DB on the same server through commands, e.g.

```
MySqlConnection conn = null;
conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = getConnection();
```

that and following queries work just fine.

What do I have to do, please?
(I looked around for about 2h regarding possible solutions, but I cannot find anything which solves my case)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and it was caused by different version of MySql data inside to connector and IDE plugin.
So We don't use the last version; our configuration is: Connector 6.9.9 and MySql for visual studio 2.0.5.